# What are the different ways to distribute data in Hive ?

Tags: hive, distribution

What are the different ways to distribute data in Hive ? E.g. Partition By, Bucketing, distributed by etc.

Comment: even if you don't do any of this thing, data is distributed in hive. As hive works with distributed system, either it be hdfs or anything else.

Comment: Hi Gaurang, Thank You ! Though data is already distributed, I want to know more ways of data distribution(manual action), which also helps to increase the performance, like we are using partitioning

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific about your objectives? in other words what context you need partitioning in? As a matter of fact partitioning, bucketing, sorting and distributing has the same mechanism in themself -- they call a Partitioner class, HashPartitioner by default, but it's possible to use other classes, e.g. TotalOrderPartitioner, including custom ones.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Hive organizes tables into partitions. Partitioning is a way of dividing a table into related parts based on the values of particular columns like date, city, and department.